# CBR libx265, constant bitrate with HEVC

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265, libx265

I was trying to use FFmpeg and libx265, but actually, I can't find any working solution for HEVC and Constant bitrate

```
*ffmpeg -i "D:\video\Mixer test.mp4" -c:v libx265 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v 1M -minrate 1M -maxrate 1M -bufsize 2M output.ts*
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\video\Mixer test.mp4" -c:v libx265 -preset medium  -pass 1 -b:v 5000k -preset 5 -x265-params -strict-cbr -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

***Is it possible to get CBR with h265 ?***

***If it isn't possible can you share some official information about it***

Thank you.

Comment: If outputting to TS, you can set a constant bitrate at the container level by adding `-muxrate 1M` This value should be larger than the maxrate of video+audio+other streams.

Comment: It's worth trying `-x265-params strict-cbr=1` instead of `-x265-params -strict-cbr`

Comment: unfortunately `-x265-params strict-cbr=1` didn't make a trick

Comment: have you manage to make a cbr bitrate for x265?

Comment: unfortunately, no I wasn't able to find out how I can get CBR with HEVC (x265)